# Javascript Fetch Giphy Api

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to fetch Gif Image through Fetch API.
But my code is not working. I'm new to working with API's.
Please have a look at my code and help me.
Here is my code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Fetch API</title>
 
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</head>
<body>

 <script> 
  let giphyAPI = "https://github.com/Giphy/GiphyAPI/raw/master/api_giphy_header.gif";

  function setup(){

   fetch(giphyAPI)
   .then(response => {
    return response.json();
   })
   .then(json => {
    createImg(json.data[0].images.original.url);
   })
      
   .catch(err => console.log(err));

  }
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the `setup` function do? Why is it never called? Is this by any chance [tag:p5.js]?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you should do when working with APIs is refer to their documentation to find out what exactly is needed to interact with that API: [here's a link to the giphy api documentation](https://developers.giphy.com/docs/)

As you can see, the giphy API requires you use an API key, which i don't see in your code so I will assume you didn't generate one  yet.

Second of all, the URL that you're using isn't the actual giphy API url, but rather a direct link to that GIF. I would refer to the example in the documentation link i shared above to understand how to interact with this API. this is the actual API url from the example:

" http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=ryan+gosling&api_key=YOUR_API_KEY&limit=5"

Pay attention to how that API url is structured, as each part of it affects your results. If you scroll to the "Technical Documentation / Specifications" portion of the docs it will explain to you what "gifs/search" , "q", "api_key", and "limit" mean. Some general API url pieces to understand are the following

**"?"** : indicates the beginning of a query. a query for API is just a param=value pair. in this case ?q=ryan+gosling just tells the API to search for gifs that have that string in it

**"&"** : is used for concatenation of different parameters for that query.

here are some general steps for you to follow to get this to work

**STEP 1:** Go to https://developers.giphy.com/ and create an app. Copy the API key and store it in a variable in your javascript ( NOTE: this isn't best practice because in a public/production application you DO NOT want your API keys exposed, but for the purpose of an educational exercise its fine)

**STEP2:** Read through the docs to figure out what kind of query you'd like to do and structure your API url accordingly. Store that URL in a variable. Concatenate your apiKey variable where it belongs in the url. Alterantively you can just copy and paste the api key directly in the url.

**STEP3:** that's it the code you provided should work with these small changes. I provided a working example (you will need to enter your own api key), but I would suggest you try to do it on your own before using it as reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Fetch API</title>

      <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
      crossorigin="anonymous">
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>open the console to see the result</h1>
        <script>    
          let apiKey= 'ENTER YOUR API KEY HERE'
            let giphyAPI = `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=ryan+gosling&api_key=${apiKey}&limit=5`;

            function setup(){

                fetch(giphyAPI)
                .then(response => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(json => {
                  console.log(json)
                    console.log(json.data[0].images.original.url);
                })

                .catch(err => console.log(err));
            }
            setup();
        </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: no problem. Don't forget to mark the question as answered